# How to display .cms image file in android activity

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I am trying to display an image in an activity after parsing it's URL in JSON format from the web. The image string thus obtained has a cms file extention. I know that Volley's image loader toolbox can be used to display jpg images but with this extention it is unable to inflate the view. What should i do?

Comment: Perhaps [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) supports that file type

Comment: The .cms is likely to be an extension generated by the server that does not actually indicate the type of data contained (like .php).  Please advise the MIME type of the response when the image URL is called.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing .cms with .jpeg in the url itsel. It worked for me.